# Cross platform javascript MP3 player not working on Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, mp3, windows-phone

I am using this media player so that I can play mp3 audio files on a website and they will work on all browsers and smartphones - http://mediaelementjs.com/

However I have just been told that it is not working on Windows Phone. What's the deal with windows phone and it's built in browser?? It's pretty bad form if this plugin even supports IE6 yet it doesn't work with Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1):

This **does** supports Windows Phone. Just scroll down on its website and you'll see a support chart.

This plugin uses Flash to polyfill HTML5 video tag. So it supports IE6 but not browsers without both HTML5 and Flash support. Which means it can support WP7.5 (IE9 mobile) but not WP7.0 (IE7 mobile).